# Union all fails when using order by while creating a view

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union, sql-server-2017

I tried this query but getting the following error. I work just with the select query.I cant understand why I cant create a view using this query.

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

**Query**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[BF_Product_Categories] AS 
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
  30 AS ProductCategoryID, 
  'All Apps' AS ProductCategory, 
  'All Apps' AS Description, 
  'AA' AS Sort, 
  NULL AS ProductSubCategory, 
  NULL AS ProductSubCategoryID 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
  TOP (100) dbo.bf_productcategories.productcategoryid, 
  dbo.bf_productcategories.productcategory, 
  dbo.bf_productcategories.description, 
  dbo.bf_productcategories.sort, 
  dbo.bf_productsubcategories.productsubcategory, 
  dbo.bf_productsubcategories.productsubcategoryid 
FROM 
  dbo.bf_productcategories 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bf_productsubcategories ON dbo.bf_productcategories.productcategoryid = dbo.bf_productsubcategories.productcategoryid 
WHERE 
  (
    dbo.bf_productcategories.status = 'True'
  ) 
  AND (
    Isnull (
      (
        SELECT 
          Count(
            productcategory_subcategorymapid
          ) AS Expr1 
        FROM 
          dbo.bf_productcategory_subcategorymaps AS A 
        WHERE 
          (
            productcategoryid = dbo.bf_productcategories.productcategoryid
          )
      ), 
      0
    ) <> 0
  )
) AS AllProductCategories 
ORDER BY 
sort
```

I found questions on of this error on the StackOverflow and I tried some answers but I cant resolve it. I really need help.

Comment: What is unclear about it? The message tells you explicitly what the problem is -- "ORDER BY clause is invalid in views" --, doesn't it?

Comment: I used order by for creating this view and it was working, only after using union all this error was shown. @stickybit

Comment: @themoonchild . . . You are mistaken -- unless you used `top`, `offset` or `for xml`.

Comment: Remove the `ORDER BY` at the end. Why do you want it for anyway? Rows in views do not have ordering. They are like tables.